# Give delay after each call for function called on scroll event

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am calling checkscroll() on scroll event, which is making Ajax requests continuously.
I want to Provide some delay between calls to checkscroll(), so that my first Ajax request gets completed before second time checkscroll() gets called and make ajax request.
Here is my code:

```
function scroll(){ $(window).bind('scroll',checkScroll);}
        // calling checkScroll()   on scroll
function refresh(){flag = 1;}

function checkScroll() {


if (flag==1){ $(window).unbind('scroll');}

if(nearBottomOfPage() == 0)
{

  currentPage ++;

  xhr = $.ajax(
    {
        url : '/ideabank?page=' + currentPage,
        beforeSend: function() {
                $('#loading').show()
            },
            complete: function(){
                $('#loading').hide()
            },


        success : function(){ "can I do something here"}

    } );
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
function scroll(){ 
 $(window).bind('scroll',function(){
  setTimeOut(checkScroll,1000);
});
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
This is not working its giving `setTimeOut is not defined` error.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks People,
Its done I have given setTimeout to ajax.Posting code snippet for better understanding.

```
     setTimeout( function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",

            url: '/ideabank?page=' + currentPage,

            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#loading').show()
            },

            success: function(html) {
                $('#loading').hide()
            }
        });
    }, 500 );
```